# How to countdown timer based on database column value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, timer

There are not many solutions/tutorials on how user inserted value in database could be used as a dynamic timer countdown that does not reset after the page is refreshed.

I'm facing a problem where the value is displayed but static. Is there any other way of implementing this?

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGgBg.png) & [web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLZiw.png)

How could I add functionality to redirect or stop the countdown timer?

#### index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = 'root';
$dbName = 'student';

$conn = mysql_connect ($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die ('MySQL connect failed. ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbName,$conn);

$duration="";
$query="select duration from table1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$duration=$row["duration"];
}

$_SESSION["duration"]=$duration;
$_SESSION["start_time"]=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$end_time=$end_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$_SESSION["duration"].'minutes',strtotime($_SESSION["start_time"])));
$_SESSION["end_time"]=$end_time;
include_once 'response.php';
?>

<div id="response"> </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function()
    {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",false);
    xmlhtpp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    },1000);
    </script>
```

---

#### response.php

```
<?php

$from_start=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_end=$_SESSION["end_time"];

$first=strtotime($from_start);
$second=strtotime($to_end);

$differenceinseconds=$second-$first;

echo gmdate("H:i:s",$differenceinseconds);

?>
```

Comment: I would suggest to let javascript do the countdown once you get the end_time from the database instead of doing an ajax call to a php script. You can find plenty of examples online.

Comment: Thanks would take a look on that method. Is there timer that would even work when browser is closed and perform the required function?

Comment: your screenshot of the database (ironically, with the link text "Web") makes it seem like there are no records in the database table... Should there be 1 or more records? If so, in what conditions? And is the AJAX call to response.php supposed to update any database/session values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and found a couple issues:

1. There is a JavaScript error

   [image: js error]

   This is because there is a typo in the Javascript code on the following line:

   ```
   xmlhtpp.send(null);
   ```

   Change that to

   ```
   xmlhttp.send(null);
   ```

   And the Asynchronous requests should execute properly.
2. The line `include_once 'response.php';` will have the effect of echoing the formatted date string above the `<div>`, which will yield two formatted timestamps when the AJAX requests are running. Remove that `include_once` line to avoid that scenario.
3. The code for *response.php* doesn't call `session_start();`. Unless your error handler settings are such that E_NOTICE errors are ignored, there will likely be an error message at the top of the timer:

   > E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: _SESSION -- at line 12

See a demonstration in [this phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/anus-6wcg).